# Are two functions of the same random variable dependent? Is there a proof for this?

Tags: independence, random, covariance

Suppose x is a random variable and f(x) and g(x) are functions.  Is there a theorem that says f(x) and g(x) must be dependent so that cov(f(x),g(x)) is non-zero?

The particular problem I'm dealing with is slightly more complicated.  Consider a function of the form f(e,x), where e is a deterministic variable and x is random.  I want to know if cov(f(e,x), g(e,x)) is non-zero, where g(e,x) = f_e(e,x) is the partial of f with respect to e.

Comment: It's not true in general.  A standard counterexample is to take $X \sim U(-1,1)$, $f(x) = \operatorname{sign} x$ and $g(x) = x^2$.